# spring dm dependency issue - apache commons logging

Tags: eclipse, osgi, spring-dm

I am a novice to spring dm so pardon my simple question.
I downloaded the spring-osgi package with dependencies - 1.2.1.When I import the required plugins from the /lib folder, the plugins are not validated as they require org.apache.commons.logging.

I have the logging library but am unable to figure out where to drop it in so that this issue gets resolved and I can start developing the actual project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working!

I included the logging library by making a plugin as mentioned towards the end of this : http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2008/jw-04-osgi2.html?page=2

Comment: Congrats on the fix!  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others will be able to learn from your success.  Cheers~